ASP.NET MVC @Html.Raw(Html.Encode) replace
I am writing an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a page that renders a table with a foreach statement.
One of the lines is a text I want to split in different <BR> depending on the content
I want to split in each ; I have.. So I am using
@foreach (var model in Model.pagins)
{
    <td> @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(model.Description).Replace(";", "<br />"))</td>
}

When the text is like this "aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd" it works fine. It shows
  aaa
    <br>
    bbb
    <br>
    ccc
   <br>
    ddd

But when the text has a "+" it also split the "+". If I have "a+aa;bb+b;ccc;ddd" . It shows
 a+
<br>
aa
<br>
bb+
<br>
b
<br>
ccc
<br>
ddd

Why this is happening? How can I split it without this problem?
Thanks

Cannot reproduce your issue in my local side. If you replace model.Description with "a+aa;bb+b;ccc;ddd", do you still get the same issue? Note that I am using ASP.NET MVC (.Net Framework 4.7.2).
